# MFC - Magnifying Glass VC++

Tags: mfc

I am working on Visual C++ with MFC. I want to integrate a magnifying glass in the image processing application that I am currently working on. I have done some googling on magnifying glass projects but some are gobble-de-gook windows programming and some are too simple. Can anyone guide me with a more informed opinion as to how I could go about this, with some links or code?

NOTE : I also know about creating a device context and drawing a bitmap over it when the magnifying glass goes over a particular area. I even got a project on it. But it seems to lack some features like change size of magnifying glass etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've seen [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1602/Magnifying-Glass) but I think it has everything you need.

I would recommend to post the links that you've read in your question and explain what you mean by

> gobble-de-gook windows programming

Comment: I saw the project you gave me, its the first one that comes along when googled and I've seen this too, which is the simpler version, [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/magnify.aspx) and I see a lot of difference between the two projects.

Comment: Just use the method that best fits your need.... You wont find anything that exactly reflect the specifications you want... You need to read and understand what each one does and then go on writing YOUR OWN CODE!!!!

Comment: Also its best to post what youve tried so far and what problems/issues you're facing....

Comment: I ended up using this one. Thank you.